# Unable to get component of class 'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer' with type 'linkrewriter'

Tags: java, aem, sling

I'm upgrading an AEM project from version 6.0 to 6.3 but I'm getting the error `Unable to get component of class 'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer' with type 'linkrewriter'.`

My code

```
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.cocoon.xml.sax.AbstractSAXPipe;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.rewriter.ProcessingComponentConfiguration;
import org.apache.sling.rewriter.ProcessingContext;
import org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer;
import org.apache.sling.rewriter.TransformerFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl;

import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Properties({
        @Property(
                name = "pipeline.type",
                value = "linkrewriter",
                propertyPrivate = true
        ),
        @Property(
                name = "webconsole.configurationFactory.nameHint",
                value = "Pipeline: {pipeline.type}"
        )
})
@Component(metatype = true,
        label = "Clientlib Link Rewriter Transformer"
)
@Service(value = TransformerFactory.class)
public class LinkRewriterTransformer extends AbstractSAXPipe implements Transformer, TransformerFactory {

    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    private static final String SRC_ATTR = "src";
    private static final String JS_ELEM = "script";
    private static final String HREF_ATTR = "href";
    private static final String CSS_ELEM = "link";
    private static final String IMG_ELEM = "img";
    private static final String ANCHOR_ELEM = "a";

    private static final String DAM_PATH = "/content/dam/my-application";
    private static final String CONTENT_PATH = "/content/my-application";
    private static final String ASSET_PATH = "/etc";

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessingContext context, ProcessingComponentConfiguration config) throws IOException {
        this.request = context.getRequest();
        log.info("Transforming request {}", request.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Required for implementing interface; no action needed
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
        AttributesImpl linkAttrs = new AttributesImpl(attrs);

        String attrName = "";

        if (JS_ELEM.equalsIgnoreCase(localName) || IMG_ELEM.equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            attrName = SRC_ATTR;
        }
        else if (CSS_ELEM.equalsIgnoreCase(localName) || ANCHOR_ELEM.equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            attrName = HREF_ATTR;
        }

        if (attrName.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < linkAttrs.getLength(); i++) {
                String mappedPath = getMappedAttributeUrl(attrName, linkAttrs, i);
                if (!mappedPath.isEmpty()) {
                    linkAttrs.setValue(i, mappedPath);
                }
            }

        }

        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, linkAttrs);
    }

    private boolean pathMatches(String pathInLink) {
        return pathInLink.startsWith(ASSET_PATH) || pathInLink.startsWith(DAM_PATH) || pathInLink.startsWith
                (CONTENT_PATH);
    }

    private String getMappedAttributeUrl(String attrName, AttributesImpl linkAttrs, int index) {
        if (attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(linkAttrs.getLocalName(index))) {
            String pathInLink = linkAttrs.getValue(index);
            if (!pathInLink.isEmpty() && pathMatches(pathInLink)) {
                String mappedPath = request.getResourceResolver().map(request, pathInLink);
                log.info("Transforming {} to {}", pathInLink, mappedPath);
                return mappedPath;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer createTransformer() {
        return new LinkRewriterTransformer();
    }
}
```

My config node placed in `/apps/<application>/config/rewriter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
  contentTypes="[text/html]"
  enabled="{Boolean}true"
  generatorType="htmlparser"
  order="1"
  serializerType="htmlwriter"
  resourceTypes="[my-application/pages/base]"
  paths="[/content/my-application]"
  transformerTypes="[linkchecker,mobile,mobiledebug,contentsync,linkrewriter]">
  <transformer-mobile jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" component-optional="{Boolean}true"/>
  <transformer-mobiledebug jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" component-optional="{Boolean}true"/>
  <transformer-contentsync jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" component-optional="{Boolean}true"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AEM 6.3, the apache felix scr annotations are replaced with [OSGI R6 annotations](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/aem-6-3-article-develop.html). The linkrewriter needs to be rewritten. Please use this reference link and write the rewriter again:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html

This specific error above might be due to bundle not started. You may need to try with
/system/console/depfinder
to check if all required package dependencies are available. Earlier instance restart resolved this same error for me.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this on Monday.